# Proving that a specific change to the integrand changes the integral result

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This problem is something that intuitively seems correct to me, yet I can't find a way to prove it, or disprove it.

let $f(x)$ be a non-constant function that is continuous and differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, and assume that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(x)dx} = 0$$
now let there be some real $a \neq 0$, is it true that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{ax}f(x)dx} \neq 0$$

The reason that my instinct is to say that this is true is because at smaller valued $x$'s the function is "shrunk" and for large values it is "enlarged", but this explanation is obviously far from rigorous.

If this is true, how can it be proven? If this is false, are there any conditions that would guarantee this to be true?
Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

For the vast majority of functions $f$, it is true (particularly if you include the latter integral diverging as a possibility). But there are exceptions. It just requires that $e^axf(x)$ balance the positive increases with negative increases.

Indeed if $f$ and $g$ are functions for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dx = 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax}f(x)\,dx = A$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax}g(x)\,dx = B$ for finite $A,B$, then $h_t(x) = f(x) + tg(x)$ satisfies $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_t(x)\,dx = 0$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{at}h_t(x)\,dx = A + Bt$$
If $B \ne 0$ then letting $t = \frac {-A}B$ makes the last integral $0$.

So the reason you couldn't prove it is that it is not *always* true.

As for conditions on $f$ that would guarantee it to be true, there is one obvious one: restict $f$ to functions for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax}f(x)\,dx \ne 0$. Not helpful, but this is the point: there are all sorts of conditions that might be applied, but I don't know which would be useful to you.